# importing class will exposed other content of the file in meteor

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I created a file inside the '/imports/api' directory.

Here is a simple content on the file,

```
export default class Account {
    static get FUNCTIONS() {
        return ...
    }
    constructor() {
        this.prop1 = null;
    }
    ...
}


if (Meteor.isServer) {
    import ServerClass from './server';
    Meteor.methods(...)
}
```

This file is imported in '/server' directory. Then I imported Account class in client using

```
import Account from 'imports/api/Account'
```

Does it expose the server side codes inside Meteor.isServer (the Meteor methods and publications)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every code that you import from the client will be in the client bundle (but not necessarily executable). In your case the user would be able to see the code block of `Meteor.isServer` in the source file of the webpage but he wouldn't be able to access functions from this part.

If you write an **import** statement **inside** a `Meteor.isServer` then the code inside this import will also be **invisible** to the client.